# Function called automatically after a given time in erlang

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

Is there any function in Erlang which gets called *automatically* after a given  amount of time and once it is triggered it should automatically be called after given amount of time, there should be no need to trigger it again and again. I am writing a module in Erlang which does cleaning task on `ejabberd server`. This module once triggered needs to be called daily automatically. Any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The library [timer](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html) provide several functions:

- `apply_after, send_after` that allow to execute a function or send a message after a certain amount of time,
- `apply_interval, send_interval` that allow to execute a function or send a message periodically.

With a combination of apply_after and apply_interval or send interval you should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 6):

See `timer:apply_after/4`.

Example:

```
-module(my_module).
-export([foo/1]).

foo(Text) ->
    error_logger:info_msg(Text, []).
```

Calling foo after 10000 milliseconds:

```
timer:apply_after(10000, my_module, foo, ["Hello!"]).
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `erlang:send_after` or `erlang:start_timer` to execute a function or to do something else. Meanwhile, you can use `timer:apply_after`, but it may cause the use rate of CPU so high, because timer is a separate process to manage timer. Creating timers using `erlang:send_after/3` and `erlang:start_timer/3` is much more efficient than using the timers provided by the timer module.

Comment: Please explain why timer:apply_after would use a lot of CPU. I thought the problem with timer was that if you use timer a lot, it might become a bottleneck, since it is a singleton.

Comment: @mattias You are right. Timer is a singleton, and every timer of users is a record which store in ets table "timer_tab". So when users using timer are too much, it will be a bottleneck. Ps: I'm not good at English,  so the sentence might be not fluent.

Comment: so in this case where he probably only has one "cleanining task on ejabberd server.", it will only take one entry in the ets table, so it is not a problem. However, if you would start thousands or more apply_after, it will be a problem?